# Should I wait more, or cut this useless stem?

Tags: houseplants, dracaena

Plant - *Dracaena reflexa* (Song of India)

Condition - One stem is budding while the other isn't. [I Had to remove the top growth.](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/29820/help-my-song-of-indiadracaena-reflexa-plant-is-dying)

What should I do: Cut the right stem completely off, or wait for some more time?

Left stem with two buds:

[image]

Right stem with no activity:

[image]

Comment: Looks like left stem greened up, and right stem is not making it. I've not worked with this plant, but given your root disaster, I'd cut. Right stem is likely taking more nutrients than it is making.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are both stems part of the same root crown? If not, the one with no buds hasn't rotted yet. If this is one plant, I would wait until all green leaves the stem before I'd cut it. Often, plants don't grow symmetrically, and it's worth a shot to see if it's just slow. Of course, when the stem is completely dead, or the lower portion of it is, it's done for in that position and you can cut it off.

The buds on the other stem look healthy and promising. They make me think that side is beginning ti root in. If you want, you can check the base of the other stem. If it's dry/dead at the bottom, you could remove the dead when cutting it off, then replant the remaining section (I see green) as a cutting.

Comment: Yes, :) They are both the part of the same root crown.

Comment: @4-K that's mostly what I figured in my answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

It depends on your desires.

If you really want to have those 2 main stems, there is a tiny chance of survival and why seal its fate?

If you don't really care, then cut it. This should tell the plant it was right to ignore the one stem, and it will fire up activity for the remaining stem, which does look pretty healthy.